# iterate through JSON?

Tags: c#, json

Can I Iterate (recursive) through this JSON?
My Problem are not the JObject rather the JArray.

This is a multi-nested JSON that I would like to go through and from which I would like to read the key and value separately.

```
{
  "DataValid": 1,
  "Identifier": "865263040394502",
  "RecordType": "D",
  "TypeD_data": {
    "tStat": {
      "lDistance": 545190,
      "lUpTimeGps": 21074,
      "lUpTimeGsm": 34700,
      "lUpTimeMCU": 127387,
      "lUpTimeSys": 4727445,
      "lUpTimeInMotion": 66343
    },
    "header": {
      "info": 16797,
      "tTime": 1597039293,
      "reason": 4398046511136,
      "version": 1
    },
    "tAcc_bas": {
      "sXRaw": 65,
      "sYRaw": 67,
      "sZRaw": 983,
      "Status": 1,
      "sMagnitude": 66
    },
    "tAcc_ext": null,
    "tGeo_bas": {
      "polycount": 0
    },
    "tGeo_ext": null,
    "tGps_bas": {
      "Status": 11,
      "sSpeed": 79,
      "sCourse": 321,
      "fLatitude": 48.59036,
      "sAltitude": 474,
      "fLongitude": 11.56852
    },
    "tGsm_bas": {
      "ta": 0,
      "mcc": 0,
      "mnc": 0,
      "Status": 2,
      "cellcount": 0
    },
    "tGsm_ext": null,
    "tTele_ext": null,
    "tTele_int": {
      "Status": 16,
      "sTmpMCU": 2061,
      "sBatLevel": 50,
      "sBatVoltage": 3346,
      "sExtVoltage": 0
    },
    "tTele_chain": null
  },
  "DataIdentifier": "Pos",
  "Timestamp_Received": 1597039264
}
```

above there is the JSON I want to iterate through.

My Code:

```
public void SetValue(JObject value, string valueName = "")
{
   foreach (var p in value)
   {
      if (p.Value is JObject)
      {
         SetValue((JObject)p.Value, valueName + "/" + p.Key);
      }
   }
}
```

above there is my Code.

**Thank you in advance for the help.**

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateReader.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
    public List<string> GetFieldNames(dynamic input)
    {
        List<string> fieldNames = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            // Deserialize the input json string to an object
            input = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input);

            // Json Object could either contain an array or an object or just values
            // For the field names, navigate to the root or the first element
            input = input.Root ?? input.First ?? input;

            if (input != null)
            {
                // Get to the first element in the array
                bool isArray = true;
                while (isArray)
                {
                    input = input.First ?? input;

                    if (input.GetType() == typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject) ||
                    input.GetType() == typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue) ||
                    input == null)
                        isArray = false;
                }

                // check if the object is of type JObject. 
                // If yes, read the properties of that JObject
                if (input.GetType() == typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject))
                {
                    // Create JObject from object
                    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject inputJson =
                        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.FromObject(input);

                    // Read Properties
                    var properties = inputJson.Properties();

                    // Loop through all the properties of that JObject
                    foreach (var property in properties)
                    {
                        // Check if there are any sub-fields (nested)
                        // i.e. the value of any field is another JObject or another JArray
                        if (property.Value.GetType() == typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject) ||
                        property.Value.GetType() == typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray))
                        {
                            // If yes, enter the recursive loop to extract sub-field names
                            var subFields = GetFieldNames(property.Value.ToString());

                            if (subFields != null && subFields.Count() > 0)
                            {
                                // join sub-field names with field name 
                                //(e.g. Field1.SubField1, Field1.SubField2, etc.)
                                fieldNames.AddRange(
                                    subFields
                                    .Select(n =>
                                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(n) ? property.Name :
                                 string.Format("{0}.{1}", property.Name, n)));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // If there are no sub-fields, the property name is the field name
                            fieldNames.Add(property.Name + " : " + (string)property.Value<JProperty>());
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    if (input.GetType() == typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue))
                {
                    // for direct values, there is no field name
                    fieldNames.Add(string.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

        return fieldNames;
    }
```